# A query regarding SHA256 Algorithm

Tags: hash, sha-256

I am trying to code SHA256 from scratch to understand its implementation based on the wiki pseudo code as its clear enough. But I am running into problems with the calculation of W[i] for the first block. I am sure I am missing the logic somewhere. Given a data string of size 80 Bytes (in Hex): "**02000000aaf8ab82362344f49083ee4edef795362cf135293564c4070000000000000000c009bb6222e9bc4cdb8f26b2e8a2f8d163509691a4038fa692abf9a474c9b21476800755c02e17181fe6c1c3**"

After padding it results in the data string of 128 Bytes (in Hex):
"**02000000aaf8ab82362344f49083ee4edef795362cf135293564c4070000000000000000c009bb6222e9bc4cdb8f26b2e8a2f8d163509691a4038fa692abf9a474c9b21476800755c02e17181fe6c1c3800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000280**"

Now this is split into 2 chunks of 64 Byte each:
"**02000000aaf8ab82362344f49083ee4edef795362cf135293564c4070000000000000000c009bb6222e9bc4cdb8f26b2e8a2f8d163509691a4038fa692abf9a4**"

"**74c9b21476800755c02e17181fe6c1c3800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000280**"

Now when we start processing the first chunk how do we populate the 64-entry message schedule array w[0..63] of 32-bit words. Wiki says:
*"(The initial values in w[0..63] don't matter, so many implementations zero them here)"
copy chunk into first 16 words w[0..15] of the message schedule array*

So I try to populate the message schedule array as as follows:

W[0]=0200

W[1]=0000

W[2]=aaf8

W[3]=ab82

W[4]=3623 and so on upto W[15].

The values W[16] to W[63] are all set to 0.

But these values seem incorrect. What am I doing wrong here. Can someone please point to what is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> W[0]=0200

Here's your problem - with SHA-256, each word is 32 bits, not 16.

So, this should be:

```
W[0] = 02000000 
W[1] = aaf8ab82
W[2] = 362344f4
```

etc...